# Range Header for HttpWebRequest (missing property?)

Tags: vb.net, http-headers, httpwebrequest

My code generates an error saying

`The 'Range' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.`

From what I understand, the Range header cannot be set using

`wReq.Headers.Add("Range", "ValueHere")`

It must be set using the relevant property of the HTTPWebRequest object. just like with User-Agent header and other restricted headers.

My problem is, I cannot find a `Range` property in the HTTPWebRequest object.

What should I do to set the range?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx, Ctrl+F, "range": [`AddRange(int, int)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fy67z6d(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks man! though do I have to parse the string to get the "from" and "to" integer values?

Comment: @IbrahimD. You mention "the string" in your comment but not in the question. Can you tell us more about that string, such as where it comes from?